# jQuery Horizontal Scale/Dial/Rule

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to find a jQuery plugin that will do a scale like this but I haven't been able to find anything. Basically, the arrows would stay put and you can slide the rule left/right to change the value.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: if you search Google for linear/horizontal gauge plugins you'll find a bunch https://www.google.ca/search?q=jquery+linear+gauge+plugin&oq=jquery+linear+gauge+plugin&aqs=chrome..69i57.3462j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Kind of - but not the result I'm looking for.

Comment: I think your only option might be to use a linear gauge and do custom javascript logic to keep the needle centered while changing the scale based on user input

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this would be to use a linear gauge (as i've stated in my comment) and use some custom javascript to force it to behave as you'd like, here's a super basic fiddle to show you what i mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/vb4ak4zx/4/

HTML:

```
<button class="testbtn">
CHANGE VALUE
</button>
<div style="height:150px">
    <div id="lineargauge"></div>
</div>
```

javascript/jquery

```
$(function () {
            $("#lineargauge").igLinearGauge({
                height: "80px",
                width: "100%",
                value: 150,
                minimumValue: 100,
                maximumValue: 200,
                ranges: [
                    {
                        startValue: 100, endValue: 150, name: "range1"
                    },
                    {
                        startValue: 150, endValue: 200, name: "range2"
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".testbtn", function(){
        $("#lineargauge").igLinearGauge({
                height: "80px",
                width: "100%",
                value: 50,
                minimumValue: 0,
                maximumValue: 100,
                ranges: [
                    {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 50, name: "range1"
                    },
                    {
                        startValue: 50, endValue: 100, name: "range2"
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```